# How good is the approximation $e^{-x} = \left(1- \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

We know that for $n\rightarrow \infty$, the above converges. But how good of an approximation is it for non arbitrarily large $n$ (i.e. $n << \infty$)?

Comment: Well, never great if you let $x$ get large enough; (1 - x/n)^n is a polynomial and so its absolute value goes to $\infty$ as $x$ gets large. Do you mean how good is the approximation on some fixed interval of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If I remember right this series was slow, there are other series that converge to e^{-x} faster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Taylor series of the $\log$ and $\exp$ functions,
\begin{align*}
\left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right)^n & = \exp \left( {n\log \left( {1 - \frac{x}{n}} \right)} \right) = \exp \left( {n\left( { - \frac{x}{n} + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{x^2 }}{{n^2 }}} \right)} \right)} \right)
\\ & = e^{ - x} \exp \left( {\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right)} \right) = e^{ - x} \left( {1 + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{{x^2 }}{n}} \right)} \right),
\end{align*}
as $n\to +\infty$, provided $|x| \ll n$.

Answer (score 1):

In the same spirit as @Gary's answer, consider
$$y=\left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)^n\implies \log(y)=n \log\left(1 - \frac{x}{n} \right)$$ Using Taylor series when $n$ is large
$$\log(y)=n\left(-\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^2}{2 n^2}-\frac{x^3}{3
   n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\right)$$
$$\log(y)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2 n}-\frac{x^3}{3 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^{-x}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2 n}+\frac{x^3 (3 x-8)}{24
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

There is an analytical answer to this question.

Let us assume an absolute error $\epsilon$, such that

$$\left(1+\dfrac xn\right)^ne^{-x}=1-\epsilon.$$

With $t:=1+\dfrac xn$, we have

$$t^ne^{n(1-t)}=1-\epsilon$$

or

$$-te^{-t}=-\frac{\sqrt[n]{1-\epsilon}}e$$ and

$$t=-W\left(-\frac{\sqrt[n]{1-\epsilon}}e\right),$$

$$x=-n\left(W\left(\frac{\sqrt[n]{1-\epsilon}}e\right)+1\right).$$